# Is it possible to save your values local?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, save

Is it possible to save your values local in visual studio and not in a local database ? If someone types something in a textbox and saves it i wanna save that value and if the user opens visual studio i wanna show the value that he saved.

Comment: how many of those value do you wanna save?

Comment: separated file, cookies (for web), and so on

Comment: @active92 depends on how many values the user saves

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov  for Windows Form

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities to do that. csv-File, txt-File, xml, Excel, registry...

Comment: @h.t.a i'm not sure why you would like to save all the values but if there's only one value, you can save it in properties.settings.default

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how this works. Visual Studio is a developement environment. It's only intended for developement. Your users should never see it.

When you release an application to your users distribute the executable by an installer. Visual Studio can help you to generate an installer. Keyword: ClickOnce

Comment: @h.t.a comments are there to help original author to improve post. If author did not consider information important enough to be added to the question than one can safely ignore comments and answer question as it stands.